# cppcheck dereference null pointer

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I know cppcheck can check dereferencing of null pointers on variables. For example, this would trigger cpp check:

```
int* a = NULL;
*a = 5;
```

Is it possible to configure cppcheck so that it verifies also pointers returned by functions? Something like this:

```
int* foo() { return NULL; }
void main()
{
  int a = *foo();
}
```

And, if that is possible, would it also work on smart pointers?

Comment: the first one is not a null pointer, is an uninitialized pointer

Comment: Did you try checking the code with cppcheck?

Comment: thanks @bolov - I edited the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I did and cppcheck says nothing about the function call...

Comment: `main` must return `int` in C++.

Comment: Don't forget that in C++ you should use `nullptr`.

Comment: Unless `cppcheck` can deduce that the function always returns `NULL` then this is pretty hard to see in advance.

Comment: In general no. First of all function body can be in different compilation unit. Second - it would only work in very trivial cases, so it has zero value.

Answer (score 2):

Running your example with the latest revision of Cppcheck (https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/commit/e6d692d9605850cf98153a4825e353898b9320a2) gives

```
$ g++ -c nullPointer.cpp && cppcheck --enable=all --inconclusive nullPointer.cpp
Checking nullPointer.cpp ...
nullPointer.cpp:4:14: error: Null pointer dereference: foo() [nullPointer]
 int a = *foo();
             ^
nullPointer.cpp:2:0: style: The function 'f' is never used. [unusedFunction]

$ more nullPointer.cpp
int * foo(void) {return 0;}
int f(void)
{
    int a = *foo();
    return a;
}
```

What version are you using?

Update: A test has been added  meanwhile to Cppchecks unit testsuite: https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/commit/fd900ab8b249eec37df706f338c227f2a9adb3ef

Update 2:
Regarding smart pointers:
Some issues with smart pointers are found.
For example for this C++ code:

```
#include <memory>
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> p(nullptr);
    int a = *p;
    return a;
}
```

Cppcheck issues an error message:

```
./cppcheck fn_nullptr.cpp
Checking fn_nullptr.cpp ...
fn_nullptr.cpp:5:14: error: Null pointer dereference: p [nullPointer]
    int a = *p;
             ^
fn_nullptr.cpp:4:28: note: Assignment 'p(nullptr)', assigned value is 0
    std::shared_ptr<int> p(nullptr);
                           ^
fn_nullptr.cpp:5:14: note: Null pointer dereference
    int a = *p;
             ^
```

But returning a null-pointer via a smart pointer currently produces no error message.
There is now a ticket requesting this: https://trac.cppcheck.net/ticket/9496